# Android SDK r22 Bouncy Castle Failing

Tags: android, build, cordova, bouncycastle

I've just updated my Android SDK to r22. I know there has been some problems with the update, but it is more focused on Android ADT for eclipse. My problem, which I've been racking my brain for about a day today, is to do with Bouncy Castle

I'm building a PhoneGap Application, and up until this update all was fine but now it is failing on building.

I'm using the command line to build the application (Using the build tools provided with PhoneGap in the /cordova folder).

The error which I get is:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/rhystague/Development/mobile-dev/android-dev/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:955: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/rhystague/Development/mobile-dev/android-dev/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:966: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
/Users/rhystague/Development/mobile-dev/android-dev/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:310: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

After this I get the stack trace. I've put it at the bottom of this question.

This is my environment and the things which I've tried.

**Environment**

```
Mac OS X 10.8.4
Java 1.6
Java 1.7
```

With Mac OS 10.8.4 the java install location is different. When I type:

```
which java
I get :/usr/bin/java

java -version
1.6 Version

/usr/libexec/java_home
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Content/Home

To run the 1.7 version I have to go to it's home directly which is 
/Library/Internet plugins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

I found that it [might be a problem with a library which is on my computer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/W8t8iGGY3fk/fpxj4GEaMSgJ), Bouncy Castle (bcprov-jdk15-143.jar). I tried those steps and all I got was a ClassDefNotDefined problem with Java.

I tried moving the file into my libs folder in my project trying to see if that would fix and nothing.

I tried updating the library to a more recent version of Bouncy Castle (bcprov-jdk15-on-149.jar)
again all I got was ClassDefNotDefined with java.

I tried a new phone gap application thinking that it might be something with the settings, however still the same problem.

To be honest I'm not a java power player so I only know basics. Maybe it is simple or maybe it is something else.

Either way I has stopped me in my tracks. I can't test anything.

Below is the stack trace following on from the error spit out

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1128)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1299)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1355)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:394)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Comment: I've restored a older version of the SDK and it works fine. I thought I would go through the motions of updating to see what was causing the error. It is the Android Build Tools which has brought this problem about. As soon as I installed that to 17 it creates this error.

Comment: After still looking around I found a article about the new ADT 22 and Tools 22 Release (http://tools.android.com/recent/adt22andtools22released). They state they're moving away from the default Sun JVM APIs and to the Bouncy Castle library instead. How do you compensate for this in the command line to prevent this build fail.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue building Phonegap android builds (using the new `phonegap run android` command in version 3) and found that I had a version of Bouncy Castle under `/Library/Java/Extensions` - I've had issues in the past with things that install JARs in here conflicting with other JARs.

When I moved the `bc*.jar` files out of this folder my Android Phonegap app started building successfully.

Note that these libraries may have been put in there by some other application / tool that this may inadvertently break, but you can't really tell what installed it until you try running that other tool and it fails!

Comment: Bingo! Fixed my problem. Will see if anything else breaks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [SpongyCastle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) if you need addition features not supported by Android.

Comment: To use this after I download it, do I put it in the libs folder of my project? Or do I have to change something in my build file?

Comment: Just add it to the libs folder if you are using Eclipse or Ant.  Not really sure what to do when using Cordova.